# Error when filtering a struct

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct

I'm trying to filter my struct:

```
class Song: CustomStringConvertible {
    let title: String
    let artist: String

    init(title: String, artist: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(title) \(artist)"
    }
}

var songs = [
    Song(title: "Song Title 3", artist: "Song Author 3"),
    Song(title: "Song Title 2", artist: "Song Author 2"),
    Song(title: "Song Title 1", artist: "Song Author 1"),
    Song(title: "Song Title 0", artist: "Song Author 1")
]
```

that dispays on an `UITableView`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: LibrarySongTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Library Cell") as! LibrarySongTableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel = songs[indexPath.row].title
    cell.artistLabel = songs[indexPath.row].artist
}
```

like this:

```
var filteredArtist = songs.filter { song -> Bool in
    return song.artist == "Artist Name"
}
```

But, I'm getting an error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` whenever I change the `cellForRowAtindexPath` to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : LibrarySongTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Library Cell") as! LibrarySongTableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel = filteredArtist[indexPath.row].title
    cell.artistLabel = filteredArtist[indexPath.row].artist
}
```

How can I fix this? I get the error on this line:

```
cell.titleLabel = filteredArtist[indexPath.row].title
```

Comment: Most probably, your `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` method does not return the correct number of (filtered!) entries.

Comment: In order to do the filtering, have you implemented the UISearchController? If not, I would recommend you read one of the tutorials. It will help your design your solution more robustly. (*I don't think you want to change your `cellForRowAt`. Oftentimes a new filtered tableView is drawn over the first one'*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *@Martin R* said in the comment, the problem is probably related to the total number of rows for your table.

Try writing updating the `tableView:tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` method like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredArtist.count
}
```